# What value of nMinimumChainWork and powLimit should I choose for my altcoin?

Tags: blockchain, difficulty, altcoin-development

```
// The best chain should have at least this much work.
        consensus.nMinimumChainWork = uint256S("0x000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000005c13f99f6d0b1a908");
```

how to calculate this parameter, i little not understand. It's not block in blockchain, how find this value if altcoin exist end i update sources with exist blockchain end for new blockchain.

```
consensus.powLimit = uint256S("00000fffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffff");
```

end about this value , how it convert to diff xxx for understand what diff is it. example diff 1, 20, 1000 etc...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> how to calculate this parameter, i little not understand. It's not block in blockchain, how find this value if altcoin exist end i update sources with exist blockchain end for new blockchain.

Because this is a new chain, the minimum should be zero.

> end about this value , how it convert to diff xxx for understand what diff is it. example diff 1, 20, 1000 etc...

It is diff 1, by definition.

Comment: if it's not new , if exist 2000+ blocks , or you mean this ?
you can write example of zero ? end how calculate it in future , how this value find I do not understand. :/

Comment: You can use the getblockchaininfo RPC to find chainwork in the future.